# Force Close error when changing from portrait to landscape

Tags: android, landscape-portrait

I am learning Android PRogramming from a book of Ed Brunette "Hello,Android"

in it the code(following) was give , i typed it as it is, still i get force close error .

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/Background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="35dip"
    >
    <Textview
        android:text="@string/main_title"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
        android:textSize="24.5sp"        />
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:stretchColumns="*">
        <TableRow>
            <Button 
                android:id="@+id/continue_button"
                android:text="@string/continue_label"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/new_button"
            android:text="@string/new_game_label"/>               
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/about_button"
                android:text="@string/about_label" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/exit_button"
                androidLtext="@string/exit_label" />

        </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

The Log Cat:

```
04-01 15:12:08.370: D/AndroidRuntime(410): Shutting down VM
04-01 15:12:08.370: W/dalvikvm(410): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
04-01 15:12:08.420: E/AndroidRuntime(410): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-01 15:12:08.420: E/AndroidRuntime(410): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.example.sudoku/org.example.sudoku.Sudoku}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class Textview
04-01 15:12:08.420: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
04-01 15:12:08.420: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-01 15:12:08.420: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2832)
04-01 15:12:08.420: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-01 15:12:08.420: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
04-01 15:12:08.420: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-01 15:12:08.420: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-01 15:12:08.420: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-01 15:12:08.420: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 15:12:08.420: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-01 15:12:08.420: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-01 15:12:08.420: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-01 15:12:08.420: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-01 15:12:08.420: E/AndroidRuntime(410): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class Textview
04-01 15:12:08.420: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
04-01 15:12:08.420: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
04-01 15:12:08.420: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
04-01 15:12:08.420: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
04-01 15:12:08.420: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
04-01 15:12:08.420: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
04-01 15:12:08.420: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
04-01 15:12:08.420: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at org.example.sudoku.Sudoku.onCreate(Sudoku.java:11)
04-01 15:12:08.420: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-01 15:12:08.420: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
04-01 15:12:08.420: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  ... 12 more
04-01 15:12:08.420: E/AndroidRuntime(410): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.Textview in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/org.example.sudoku-1.apk]
04-01 15:12:08.420: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
04-01 15:12:08.420: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
04-01 15:12:08.420: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
04-01 15:12:08.420: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
04-01 15:12:08.420: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
04-01 15:12:08.420: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
04-01 15:12:08.420: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
04-01 15:12:08.420: E/AndroidRuntime(410):  ... 21 more
04-01 15:12:12.681: I/Process(410): Sending signal. PID: 410 SIG: 9
04-01 15:12:34.881: W/KeyCharacterMap(424): No keyboard for id 0
04-01 15:12:34.881: W/KeyCharacterMap(424): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
04-01 15:30:15.661: D/AndroidRuntime(495): Shutting down VM
04-01 15:30:15.661: W/dalvikvm(495): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
04-01 15:30:15.741: E/AndroidRuntime(495): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-01 15:30:15.741: E/AndroidRuntime(495): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.example.sudoku/org.example.sudoku.Sudoku}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class Textview
04-01 15:30:15.741: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
04-01 15:30:15.741: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-01 15:30:15.741: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2832)
04-01 15:30:15.741: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-01 15:30:15.741: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
04-01 15:30:15.741: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-01 15:30:15.741: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-01 15:30:15.741: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-01 15:30:15.741: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 15:30:15.741: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-01 15:30:15.741: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-01 15:30:15.741: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-01 15:30:15.741: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-01 15:30:15.741: E/AndroidRuntime(495): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class Textview
04-01 15:30:15.741: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
04-01 15:30:15.741: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
04-01 15:30:15.741: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
04-01 15:30:15.741: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
04-01 15:30:15.741: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
04-01 15:30:15.741: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
04-01 15:30:15.741: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
04-01 15:30:15.741: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at org.example.sudoku.Sudoku.onCreate(Sudoku.java:11)
04-01 15:30:15.741: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-01 15:30:15.741: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
04-01 15:30:15.741: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  ... 12 more
04-01 15:30:15.741: E/AndroidRuntime(495): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.Textview in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/org.example.sudoku-2.apk]
04-01 15:30:15.741: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
04-01 15:30:15.741: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
04-01 15:30:15.741: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
04-01 15:30:15.741: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
04-01 15:30:15.741: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:549)
04-01 15:30:15.741: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
04-01 15:30:15.741: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
04-01 15:30:15.741: E/AndroidRuntime(495):  ... 21 more
```

i am still learning , and i searched for other questions that would help me with my problem, but it confused me as i still dont know much about android programming .

Thanks :)

Comment: please post your logcat :)

Comment: Please post your logCat info.

Comment: Find logcat.  In there, you will see the stack trace for the exception. http://www.connect-utb.com/2012/08/understanding-android-stack-traces/

Comment: hey .. i posted the log cat.. and ya the file name is same.. /res/layout/main.xml and /res/layout-land/main.xml  how to make the file code same?

Comment: @DhavalSodhaParmar: No it has different codes and design.. i used relative layout in portrait mode , and used tablelayout in landscape

Comment: @DhavalSodhaParmar This has nothing to do with the question.  You are confusing the issue.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15741487/1168654 n tell us your prob is solved or not??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your logcat:

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class Textview
E/AndroidRuntime(495):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
```

So we know that the text view is a problem.

```
<Textview
        android:text="@string/main_title"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
        android:textSize="24.5sp"        />
```

Remove the spaces before the closing tag and change Textview to TextView.

```
<TextView
        android:text="@string/main_title"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
        android:textSize="24.5sp"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a simple typo in your layout file, it should be `TextView` instead of `Textview`.